# Different user interfaces for a core functionality

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface

I have a Swift project which contains a lot of screens (got from xibs and storyboard) with many core functionalities.
Now two different projects based on these core functionalities are needed. The requirements are these projects must have different headers, cells, colors, assets, etc.
Which strategy would you follow to get different interfaces based on target/project, from a single core framework?

Answer (score 0):

**static config:**

maybe pull all project related variable, and put it in a plist file, working like archiving and unarchiving. when framework loaded, get boot info from that file.

or abstract all these info into a static class? works almost the same way.

**some way dynamic config:**

delegate pattern: every project who want to use your framework, must
implement one object with pre-designed protocol, use the object to bootstrap framework, your framework should get the project layer based question answers like header file, assets, etc.

sorry for my English, hope this helps.
;)